# How to select specific columns in spring data mongodb query ?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

This is the first time I am asking question here . Please forgive me If I am unable to explain you well.

This is simple SQL query

```
select groupId from retryBatches where campaignId = campaignId and groupId is not null;
```

How to Write the above in spring data mongodb ?

I have done this, but how to fetch only groupId

```
Query query = new Query(where("campaignId").is(campaignId).and("groupId").ne(null));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use what is called projection. This can be done like this

```
Query query = new Query(where("campaignId").is(campaignId).and("groupId").ne(null));
query.fields().include("groupId");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully something along the lines of `query.fields().include("groupId");` should do it.